What is "enumeration of the extreme points," and how can we find the decomposition of numbers.
I have the part I don't understand in reading my book.

Suppose $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\in[-1,1]$. Let $e_k (k=1,2,3,\cdots,2^n)$ be any enumeration of the extreme points of the cube $[-1,1]^n$. Then because $a:=(a_1,\cdots,a_n)\in[-1,1]^n$, we find $c_k\in[0,1]$ s.t. $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}c_k=1$ and $\displaystyle a=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}c_k e_k.$

・What is "any enumeration of the extreme points of $[-1,1]^n$" ? According to Wikipedia, the extreme point is a point that does not lie in any open line segment. In this case, are the extreme points are $-1$ and $1$ ? But if so, the number of extreme points is $2n$ instead of $2^n$. I don't understand what are $e_k.$
・I don't know how we can find such $c_k.$ I have never seen such decomposition. Is there some theorem or proposition should I use ?

For the first point, as a simple example, think about the 8 corners of a cube.

Intuitively, extreme points are vertices. $[-1,1]^n$ is a cube (square, cube, hypercube, ...) in $n$ dimensional space (the range $[-1,1]$ for each of the $n$ coordinate axes). In 3D this is $-1\leq x \leq 1, -1 \leq y \leq 1, -1 \leq z \leq 1$. The extreme points/vertices are just any string of $1$s and $-1$s - $(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, -1), (1, -1, 1),$ ... there's gonna be $2^n$ of them, they're called $e_k$, and they're treated as vectors in this problem. 

The next part is talking about a convex combination of those vertices. In a convex shape or polyhedron (such as an $n$ dimensional cube), any point on the interior of the shape is a convex combination of the vertices. If $a$ is a point where each coordinate is between $-1$ and $1$, it makes sense that $a$ is inside the cube, so it can be written as a convex combination of the $e_k$s (the vertices). 

Operations research is a rich field, and it can get confusing fast. If any of this doesn't completely make sense, feel free to follow up.
